# ViewModel NameSpace

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel as such:

```
    namespace Lipton.Areas.Drugs.Models
    {
      public class DrugViewModel
      {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblDrug> DrugList { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

The above works fine. The reason why it works is because for tblDrug is in the appropriate namespace:
Lipton.Areas.Drugs.Models. What happens though if I need to add an IEnumerable for another table - tblEmp which is in a totally different namespace (Lipton.Areas.Empl.Models:

```
    namespace Lipton.Areas.Drugs.Models
    {
      public class DrugViewModel
      {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblDrug> DrugList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblEmp> EmpList { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

How would I modify the above code to work due to the namespace issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) directive in order to bring the namespace into scope so that you could directly use the types declared in this namespace without fully qualifying them:

```
namespace Lipton.Areas.Drugs.Models
{
    using Lipton.Areas.Empl.Models

    public class DrugViewModel
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblDrug> DrugList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblEmp> EmpList { get; set; }
     }
}
```

I don't even know why this question is tagged with [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). That's basic [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly add the namespace for `tblEmp`

```
namespace Lipton.Areas.Drugs.Models
{
  public class DrugViewModel
  {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblDrug> DrugList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Lipton.Areas.Empl.Models.tblEmp> EmpList { get; set; }
  }
}
```